# how to create unlimited product ids in itunes for inapp purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, non-renewing-subscription

I'am working on an application where user will be showed thumbnails of the images in image gallary. To view it in HD mode and enable sharing and downloading, user need to purchase it. and since this app has login feature, each user has his own gallary of images. Now, I'am confused how could i create product ids in itunes when the content is user specific and dynamic. I mean number of images in gallery may increase upon uploading from some server side. Also these purchases need to be non renewable. Please help me out.

Comment: a renewable model (unlock all images for 1 year = $??) would be better. purchasing each image individually is quite annoying from user point of view and could lead to rejection from apple even.

Comment: @Shubhank: I have cater this in two ways: 1. unlock all images in a single go for a specific duration. 2. unlock only intended images for specific duration in case user wont opt to pay for whole bunch of images and interested i some specific images.

Comment: i guess make the - iAP - Unlock one image for xyz price.. In it unlock the image server side for the user for that - login id/pass. That way user would have access to image on other device also.

Comment: The standard approach for this is to create consumable in-app purchases for "credits".  The user can then use these credits to purchase the images/items.  You keep track of their purchased items in your own server

Comment: @Paulw11: Thanks. This sounds viable. Will try this.